# CSS margins messing up white space - best way to format?

Tags: css, whitespace, margin, padding

Okay, so I have the following code below:

```
<ul class="noindent">
    <li class="indexlist"><p class="index">Brixham Town Centre</p></li>
    <li class="indexlist"><p class="index">Kingswear</p></li>
    <li class="indexlist"><p class="index">Paignton Bus Station</p></li>
    <li class="indexlist"><p class="index">South Devon College</p></li>
    <li class="indexlist"><p class="index">St Marychurch</p></li>
    <li class="indexlist"><p class="index">Torbay Hospital</p></li>
    <li class="indexlist"><p class="index">Torquay Town Centre</p></li>
    <li class="indexlist"><p class="index">The Willows</p></li>
</ul>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.indexlist {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    height: 60px;
    background: url(images/indexlistbg.gif) repeat-x;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: -15px;
    margin: 0;
}
.noindent {
    padding: 0;
}
p.index {
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

You can see the page in action at: http://new.mystoptorbay.co.uk/. I don't want the white space underneath each li, but I can see that the padding-top attribute is messing things up. What would be the best way to allow the text to float central vertically, and have no white space between each li?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the padding messing up but the margin.

```
p.index {
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin: 0; // remove margin
}
```

Even better to center verticaly the text am make it 60px height would be like this:

```
p.index {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 60px;
}
```

The problem was that the `p` element has some user agent style:

```
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
```

It adds before and after a margin of `1em` to make distinct the paragraphs. The `p` tags should be used in text, while in this case it should be better to use `span`s or `a` if you need links.

Comment: Thanks! That's worked - I can't quite understand exactly how, but thank you :)

Comment: @Elliot, you can mark the anwer as accepted :) I add some details to explain why its happening.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the rule `p.index{padding-top:15px;}` and to your `.indexlist` rules, add `overflow:auto;`

Comment: Not really the "right" solution. Just "hiding" spacing that should be resetted this way. It might cause more bugs and other errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your P elements still have margin. Just reset this to 0 and you will be fine.

```
p.index {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Try using the element inspector in Chrome to easily fix these "bugs"
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/dom-and-styles